# Get first occurrence of a word in a comma separated string

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a specific field in the database called products, which stores data as comma separated.

What I want to be able to do is retrieve the first occurrence of a word in the whole string, which contains the "IN" characters and then get the number that comes after "IN".

What I tried is the following code, but this will return "15,12".

`products = "IN15,IN12"`

`products = "IN 15,IN12"`

`products = "TEST,IN15"`

`WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(products, '^IN') THEN regexp_replace(products, '[^0-9]', '')`

In all of the above cases, where either there is a comma after IN or there is not a comma, I would like the output to be "15".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SQL> with test (products) as
  2    (select 'IN15,IN12'  from dual union all
  3     select 'IN 15,IN12' from dual union all
  4     select 'TEST,IN15'  from dual
  5    )
  6  select products,
  7    regexp_substr(substr(products, instr(products, 'IN') + 2), '\w+') result
  8  from test;

PRODUCTS   RESULT
---------- ----------------------------------------
IN15,IN12  15
IN 15,IN12 15
TEST,IN15  15

SQL>
```

What does it do:

- `INSTR` finds occurrence of the `IN` within the string
- `SUBSTR` returns everything that follows the first `IN`
- `REGEXP_SUBSTR` extracts the first word in that substring

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it's what I needed